# Grouping multiple records, into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following query:

```
SELECT  C.AGENCY_NAME, B.PROJECT_NUMBER, B.PROJECT_NAME, D.CONTRACT_NO, 
            B.PROJECT_START_DATE,
            CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'JUL' THEN
                F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                    + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                    WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                    AND (A.MONTH = 'JUL') ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'July',

            CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' THEN
                F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                    + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                    WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                    AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'August'

        FROM EXPENSES A
        INNER JOIN PROGRAMS B ON A.PROGRAM_ID = B.PROGRAM_ID
        INNER JOIN AGENCIES C ON B.AGENCY_ID = C.AGENCY_ID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACTS D ON B.CONTRACT_ID = D.CONTRACT_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_DATA E ON A.INVOICE_NUMBER = E.INVOICE_NUMBER_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE F ON E.STATUS = F.PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID
```

I get the following results:

AGENCY_NAME PROJECT_NUMBER  PROJECT_NAME    CONTRACT_NO PROJECT_START_DATE  July    August

```
Test Agency 1   proj54891   Test Project Name 1 C567HR8E    2012-05-23 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL
Test Agency 1   proj54891   Test Project Name 1 C567HR8E    2012-05-23 00:00:00.000 NULL    Rejected- Grants-09/25/2013
Test Agency 1   proj54891   Test Project Name 1 C567HR8E    2012-05-23 00:00:00.000 Approved- Administrator-09/25/2013  NULL
Test Agency 1488    proj54891   Test Project Name 34    C5676542H9  2013-04-03 00:00:00.000 Approved-Agency-10/12/2013  NULL
```

How can I change it to get the following results:

```
AGENCY_NAME PROJECT_NUMBER  PROJECT_NAME    CONTRACT_NO PROJECT_START_DATE  July    August

Test Agency 1   proj54891   Test Project Name 1 C567HR8E    2012-05-23 00:00:00.000 Approved- Administrator-09/25/2013      Rejected- Grants-09/25/2013
Test Agency 1488    proj54891   Test Project Name 34    C5676542H9  2013-04-03 00:00:00.000 Approved-Agency-10/12/2013  NULL
```

so that the similar agency, project_number, and project name are only in one row?
I just need to group the like projects into a single row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can group results with the GROUP BY statement.
In this case I figure it would be something like this:

```
  GROUP BY(C.AGENCY_NAME, B.PROJECT_NUMBER)
```

You use this if you want to select some aggregate value. For example the SUM of a certain column, or a simple COUNT of the number of rows in each group.

Otherwise, if you do not want to aggregate something, but just want to know each distinct entries, then you would use SELECT DISTINCT. So that would be something like:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(C.AGENCY_NAME, B.PROJECT_NUMBER)
```

So, it kind of depends what you want to do exactly.

Comment: there's no way to use an aggregate here.  I need to display all the fields, but combine the results.  I gave the exact result I need above.  I need to combine the two records into one.  (When the expense is in July, or the expense is in august, this will produce two rows.  I need to combine these two rows (with the same agency, and project number into one)

Comment: I will need a much more sophisticated way to combine these records that a simple group by

Comment: Then you should make it clearer how to combine the results. You gave 1 example, but it is not a definition. It surely looks like an aggregation, so its most likely a group by you need, although perhaps not a simple one.

Comment: I think you will first need to fetch all unique combinations by using a  SELECT DISTINCT subquery and then JOIN that result with the months you want to append. I think you will need a separate JOIN to  PEOPLE_SOFT_DATA E for each month separately. Then I suppose you will need some (CASE?) logic to combine it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.AGENCY_NAME, B.PROJECT_NUMBER, B.PROJECT_NAME, D.CONTRACT_NO, 
            B.PROJECT_START_DATE,
            CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'JUL' THEN
                F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                    + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                    WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                    AND (A.MONTH = 'JUL') ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'July',

            CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' THEN
                F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                    + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                    WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                    AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'August'

        FROM EXPENSES A
        INNER JOIN PROGRAMS B ON A.PROGRAM_ID = B.PROGRAM_ID
        INNER JOIN AGENCIES C ON B.AGENCY_ID = C.AGENCY_ID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACTS D ON B.CONTRACT_ID = D.CONTRACT_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_DATA E ON A.INVOICE_NUMBER = E.INVOICE_NUMBER_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE F ON E.STATUS = F.PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID
```

or use GROUP BY

```
SELECT AGENCY_NAME, PROJECT_NUMBER, PROJECT_NAME, CONTRACT_NO, PROJECT_START_DATE, July, August
(
    SELECT C.AGENCY_NAME, B.PROJECT_NUMBER, B.PROJECT_NAME, D.CONTRACT_NO, 
                B.PROJECT_START_DATE,
                CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'JUL' THEN
                    F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                    (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                        + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                        WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                        AND (A.MONTH = 'JUL') ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'July',

                CASE WHEN E.CHECK_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' THEN
                    F.NAME + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_DATE, 101) + ' ' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHK# ' END 
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECK_NUMBER) ELSE /*START CODE IF PEOPLESOFT DATA DOESN'T EXIST*/
                    (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Approved-' WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 'Hold-' ELSE 'Rejected-' END
                        + WORKFLOW_NAME + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101) FROM FINANCE_WORKFLOW_DETAILS G, FINANCE_WORKFLOW H 
                        WHERE G.WORKKFLOW_ID_STATE = H.FINANCE_WORKFLOW_ID AND G.INVOICE_ID = A.INVOICE_NUMBER AND A.PROGRAM_ID = G.PROGRAM_ID
                        AND A.MONTH = 'AUG' ORDER BY DATE DESC) END 'August'

            FROM EXPENSES A
            INNER JOIN PROGRAMS B ON A.PROGRAM_ID = B.PROGRAM_ID
            INNER JOIN AGENCIES C ON B.AGENCY_ID = C.AGENCY_ID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACTS D ON B.CONTRACT_ID = D.CONTRACT_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_DATA E ON A.INVOICE_NUMBER = E.INVOICE_NUMBER_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE F ON E.STATUS = F.PEOPLE_SOFT_PAYMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID
) a
GROUP BY AGENCY_NAME, PROJECT_NUMBER, PROJECT_NAME, CONTRACT_NO, PROJECT_START_DATE, July, August
```

http://www.learn-with-video-tutorials.com - IT video tutorials

Comment: This will produce multiple records with the same agency, project, project name with different months filled in.  Not what I need.  I need one record, grouped by project, project_name, and agency, with different months combined to the same record.  If you look at my question, you can see the results I need.